# Baby Rudin Exercise 2.21

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness

The set up is as follows:

"
Let $A$ and $B$ be separated subsets of some $\mathbb{R}^k$, and suppose $a \in A$, $b \in B$, and define

$p(t) = (1-t)a + tb$, for $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Put $A_0 = p^{-1}(A), B_0 = p^{-1}(B)$. [Thus $t \in A_0$ if and only if $p(t) \in A$]. "

Now part (a) asks to show that $A_0$ and $B_0$ are separated subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

My question is what exactly is the relevance of $\mathbb{R}^k$ here, and doesn't this already show $A_0$ and $B_0$ are seperated?

For instance, just from the definition alone, can't I conclude the following?

$t \in A_0 \iff p(t) \in A $

$\implies  p(t) \notin \bar{B} \hspace{2pt}$ (since $A \cap \bar{B} = \emptyset$)

$\iff  t \notin \bar{B_0} $

Thus $A_0 \cap \bar{B_0} = \emptyset$.

The exact same argument follows for$ \bar{A_0} \cap B_0 = \emptyset$.

Am I missing something in this approach?

Comment: The implication from $p(t)\in A$ to $p(t)\not\in\overline{B}$ only goes in one direction (though you only need that one direction).

Comment: Oh true. Fixed that. But that aside, does this suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, how do you know that $p(t)\not\in\overline{B}$ implies $t\not\in\overline{B}_0$?  It is immediate from the definitions that $p(t)\in B$ is equivalent to $t\in B_0$, but to make an analogous statement about the closures you will need to use something special about the function $p$ (and in fact the implication will only go in one direction).

Comment: I understand, thank you.